# Join two tables and show the retrieved information in thymeleaf table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

i have two tables first one is Filiere and the second is Cycle, related by a one to many relationship,which a Filiere can have a Cycle and Cycle can have multiple Filiere,and i want to display infos about all the filieres including Cycle name in a table using thymeleaf

```html
package org.pfe.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
@Entity
public class Cycle implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique=true,nullable = false)
    private String nom;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cyc")
    private Set<Filiere> filList=new HashSet<>();


    public Cycle() {
        super();
    }


    public Cycle(String nom, Set<Filiere> filList) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.filList = filList;
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }


    public Set<Filiere> getFilList() {
        return filList;
    }


    public void setFilList(Set<Filiere> filList) {
        this.filList = filList;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    


    
    
    
}
```

```html
package org.pfe.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
public class Filiere {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "ne doit pas etre null" )
    @NotNull
    private String nom;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @NotNull(message = "la date ne doit pas etre null")
    private Date dateCreation;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="dept_id")
    private Departement dept;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cycle_id")
    private Cycle cyc;
    
    
    

}
```

Can you plz help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

you put the cycle object to the model.

For Example:

model.addAttribute("cycleList", listOfCycle);

In thymeleaf

```
 <tr th:each="cycle:${cycleList}">
            <td th:text="${cycle.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${cycle.nom}"></td>
            <td>
                <div th:each="filList:${cycle.filList}">
                    <p th:text="${filList.id}"></p>
                    <p th:text="${filList.nom}"></p>
                    <p th:text="${filList.dateCreation}"></p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This is how you can get the data in thymeleaf.